# How to expose a Twig Extension as service of a bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.5

I have written a small twig extension which deliever some functions.

This extension is bundled and I want to expose it as service of the bundle, so I have created the services.yml:

```
services:
    twig.job_action_extension:
        class: WebBundle\Template\JobActionExtension
        arguments: ["@translator"]
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

But it seems that the extension is never exposed.
Running `php app/console container:debug` doesn't list my service.

Isn't it possible to register a twig extension as service like [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)?
Or do I need to create an extension under DependencyInjection like [here](https://github.com/LaKrue/TwigstringBundle) if I want to contribute it as part of my bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer digging a little bit deeper.

I need to refer from the *app/config/config.yml* to the bundle *services.yml* ([source](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#importing-configuration-with-imports)).

If I want to do it automatically I really need the extension ([source](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) and the above referred [extension](https://github.com/LaKrue/TwigstringBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/LKTwigstringExtension.php)).

So to answer my both questions:

1. Yes it is possible to register an extension as service.
2. You need the extension under DependencyInjection, if you want to autoload your extension without adjusting the *app/config/config.yml*.